# F# XML Type Provider - Using an XSD

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I am probably missing the boat here, but how can you build a reusable tool that uses the XML Type Provider if the XML you are giving to XMLProvider doesn't have all of the possible elements? In other words, is there any way to use an XSD? I know I could try to generate sample XML from an XSD but I'm wondering if I am approaching this incorrectly.

Comment: Have a look at this issue - https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/57? It is work in progress at the moment.

Comment: There's now a [branch of FSharp.Data](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/tree/XsdProvider) with work on adding XSD-parsing functionality to XmlProvider. There is *also* a [separate project](https://giacomociti.github.io/FSharp.Data.Xsd/), in early alpha stages, to do the same thing. (The author created it as a separate project so as not to interfere with the XsdProvider branch). I've used the separate project in a proof-of-concept project, and it worked for me, though I'm sure there are still plenty of bugs to find. But you could give that a try.

Comment: this separate project is now sufficiently complete and stable (disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: @GiacomoCiti Tried your 1.0 version.. and it appears to fail silently (in fsx file, using a collada 1.5 schema from there: https://www.khronos.org/collada/ with a blender exported .dae xml file). Cannot even access the first node. :(

Comment: @GiacomoCiti Taking it all back - seems to work now - albeit a bit differently as expected. Great job!

Comment: @BitTickler the collada schema is huge and it also imports many MathML xsd files. The type provider uses a local cache, that's probably why things get better after a while. As for the unexpected stuff, please submit an issue on github; but remember that any xml data binding tool has to make some trade-off to cope with the X/O impedance mismatch

Comment: @GiacomoCiti, please consider posting your library and a description of how to use it as an answer here.

Comment: Is it still an issue cause I have a some project at work that's using XSD without any problems

Answer (score 1):

> `FSharp.Data.Xsd` augments the XML type provider of `FSharp.Data` with schema support.
> https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.Xsd/